# Setting an object instance in member variable cause an error - is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Tags: c++

I've gone through similar questions, but none of them did not explain me where I'm doing a mistake. I've got following code:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Blah blah1(100);
    Blah blah2(1000, 333, Foo(Foo::FOO_VAL2));
}
```

blah.h

```
class Blah
{
public:
    Blah(int param1, int param2 = 666, Foo foo = Foo());
    ~Blah();

    int param1;
    int param2;

    Foo foo;
};
```

blah.cpp

```
Blah::Blah(int param1, int param2, Foo foo)
{
    this->param1 = param1;
    this->param2 = param2;
    this->foo = foo;
}

Blah::~Blah() {}
```

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int param = Foo::FOO_VAL1);
    ~Foo();

    static const int FOO_VAL1 = -1;
    static const int FOO_VAL2 = 0;

    int param;
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(int param)
{
    this->param = param;
}

Foo::~Foo() {}
```

And when I ran the application, it cause:

> ‘Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

I know that the mistake is on the assignment `this->foo = foo;`, but what does it mean? Why it is failing? What should I do different way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Norepro](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1BlQLH6CfCGCf9OO). I did have to remove the `param` from `Foo` though, your code snippet isn't complete I think, add the `param` member. Give us a MCVE.

Comment: "`this->param = param;`" won't compile because there's no such class member called "param", and, once that's fixed, the shown code compiles without any errors. Please show real code, in your question, that produces the alleged compilation error. Make sure to try it yourself, to verify that it does produce the claimed compilation error, before asking other people to spend their time to help you.

Comment: Don't use the constructor body to initialize members. Use the constructors initialization list.

Comment: Still no repro even after edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought my code snippets will be enough, I thought it is some type of beginners mistake (and it was). I don't know why, but @SamVarshavchik was right, this code snippet compiles without any errors - probably due to the fact, that class member `this->foo` is not used anywhere else. But `this->foo` was real problem in my real code - unfortunately I am not able to show you the source code. Thank you for your time, @SombreroChicken and @SamVarshavchik, you are right, next time I'll try my snippet, I didn't know that it will be necessary. @JesperJuhl 's answer was the solution, thanks.

Comment: Please @JesperJuhl, could you, please, post your answer as the solution? I would like to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the constructor body to initialize members. Use the constructors initialization list.